# PyQt - How to parallel the functioning of an entire object

Tags: python, qt, parallel-processing, pyqt5

My issue follows: I've a main GUI that manages different connections with an instrument and elaborates the data coming from this latter according to the user choices. I designed a class `InstrumentController` that manages all the methods to speak with the instrument (connect, disconnect, set commands and read commands).

Obviously I'd like to make the instrument management to work parallel to the GUI application. I've already explored the `QThread`, and in particular the `moveToThread` option widely detailed on the Internet. However, though it works, I don't like this strategy for some reason:

1. I don't want my object to be **a thread** (subclass `QThread`). I'd like to maintain the modularity and generality of my class.
2. ...even if it has to be, it doesn't solve the next point
3. **QThread, obviously, works on a single callback base**. Thus, I've an extra workload to either create a thread per each `InstrumentController` method or accordingly configure a single thread each time a method is called (I'm not expecting the methods of the object to work concurrently!)

As a consequence, I'm seeking a solution that allows me to have the `InstrumentController` entity to work like a separate program (deamon?) but that must be strongly linked to the main GUI (it has to continuously communicate back and forth),  so that I need signals from GUI to be visible by this object and viceversa. I was exploring some solution, namely:

1. Create an extra event loop (QEventLoop) that works parallel to the main loop, but the official docs is very slim and I found little more on the Internet. Therefore I don't even know if it is practicable.
2. Create a separate process (another Qt application) and search for an effective protocol of communication.

Aware that venturing into one of these solution might be time-consuming and possibly -waisting, I'd like to ask for any effective, efficient and practicable suggestion that might help with my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem, but if you are going to have multiple interfaces, a possible solution could be to create a *single* controller (that would have its own thread) which would act as an interface to the actual `InstrumentController` interfaces, similarly to what QNetworkAccessManager does.

Comment: I'm trying to build a single class interface towards the instrument. As far as Qt thread is structured (my understanding), you can instantiate a thread object and pass a callback to be executed in its run() routine, you cannot _thread_ an entire object so that every call to a member of its is run in the thread. That's the point of the question.

Comment: Yes, you can run members in the thread, you only cannot directly call them. A common approach is to use a python `Queue` to queue "commands" (which can even be direct references to functions), and in the `run()` you add a while loop that waits for new items in the queue and eventually calls them if they're functions. It is conceptually an event loop, where the "events" are objects in the queue, which are processed in sequence (exactly like the Qt event loop).

Comment: @Buzz Subclassing `QThread` is definitely not the same as `moveToThread`, so you seem to have misunderstood that. It is also wrong to say that a separate thread is needed for each method call. All that's actually needed is a pair of custom signals to send and receive commands between a single worker thread and the gui thread. It's just a simple server/client setup. The same thing could easily be achieved with [local sockets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro, if you read carefully I never said that subclassing `QThread` and `moveToThread` are the same stuff. I just said I explored both and neither get me the solution. The use of a thread per each task, again, is an option as I wrote, not a necessity. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion about the local socket, I'll explore this solution, as well as the one suggested by @musicamante!

Comment: @Buzz You said: "you cannot thread an entire object so that every call to a member of its is run in the thread. That's the point of the question". But that's exactly what `moveToThread` would allow. For example, if all the relevant members were wrapped as pyqt slots, you could call them with [QMetaObject.invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod). Your question and comments only talk about subclassing `QThread` and overriding `run()`. I don't see much evidence there that you've properly considered all the other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As far as I learned from documentation and Internet posts, `moveToThread` functions together with the `started` signal to be connected to the specific function (member in this case) that is meant to be executed. Meaning that `obj.moveToThread(th); obj.method_1()` would no way execute in the `th` thread: that was my point. I honestly was unaware of the QMetaObject.invokeMethod, I'll have a deeper insight.

Comment: @Buzz But if you connected `started` to `method_1`, then it *would* execute in the thread. Cross-thread signals are thread-safe because they automatically serialise the slot-call as an event and post it to the event-queue of the receiving thread. So you just need to think in terms of invoking methods using signals and slots (or via QMetaObject) rather than calling them directly. This is conceptually equivalent to e.g. serialising requests and replies as json, and exchanging them via a local socket.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is that a QThread is only a wrapper to a OS thread.

`moveToThread()` does not move an object to the `QThread` object, but to the thread that it refers to; in fact, a QThread might have its own [`thread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) *property* (as Qt documentation reports, it's "the thread in which the object lives").

With that in mind, `moveToThread()` is not the same as creating a QThread, and, most importantly, a QThread does not work "on a single callback base". What's important is what it's executed in the thread that QThread refers to.

When a QThread is started, whatever is executed in the threaded function (aka, `run()`) is actually executed in *that* thread.

Connecting a function to the `started` signal results in executing that function in the OS thread the QThreads refers to.
Calling a function from any of that functions (including the basic `run()`) results in running *that* function in the other thread.

If you want to execute functions for that thread, those functions *must* be called from there, so a possible solution is to use a Queue to pass that function reference to ensure that a command is actually executed in the other thread. So, you can run a function on the other thread, as long as it's *called* (not just referenced to) from that thread.

Here's a basic example:

```
import sys
from queue import Queue
from random import randrange
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    log = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        self.keepRunning = True
        while self.keepRunning:
            wait = self.queue.get()
            if wait is None:
                self.keepRunning = False
                continue
            count += 1
            self.log.emit('Process {} started ({} seconds)'.format(count, wait))
            self.sleep(wait)
            self.log.emit('Process {} finished after {} seconds'.format(count, wait))
        self.log.emit('Thread finished after {} processes ({} left unprocessed)'.format(
            count, self.queue.qsize()))

    def _queueCommand(self, wait=0):
        self.queue.put(wait)

    def shortCommand(self):
        self._queueCommand(randrange(1, 5))

    def longCommand(self):
        self._queueCommand(randrange(5, 10))

    def stop(self):
        if self.keepRunning:
            self.queue.put(None)
            self.keepRunning = False


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.startShort = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start short command')
        self.startLong = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start long command')
        self.stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop thread')
        self.log = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.startShort)
        layout.addWidget(self.startLong)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop)
        layout.addWidget(self.log)

        self.worker = Worker()

        self.worker.log.connect(self.log.append)
        self.startShort.clicked.connect(self.worker.shortCommand)
        self.startLong.clicked.connect(self.worker.longCommand)
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.worker.stop)
        self.worker.finished.connect(lambda: [
            w.setEnabled(False) for w in (self.startShort, self.startLong, self.stop)
        ])

        self.worker.start()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = Test()
test.show()
app.exec()
```